# CSS horizontal menu - why a 1px border/space in IE only?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, menu, html-lists

I've got a simple horizontal menu with a hover effect.
It displays fine in Chrome/Firefox, but in IE11 it has a 1px border between the elements.

You can see it when hovering over the left link: http://jsfiddle.net/cMeE5/

Here's a screenshot: [IE11 Screenshot http://users.telenet.be/mhd/ie11.png](http://users.telenet.be/mhd/ie11.png)

This vertical border isn't that bad, but the same kind of border is always shown on the bottom side of the menu item (but it doesn't reproduce in JSFiddle).

I also tried added a full CSS Reset but that doesn't change anything.

Here's the code on JSFiddle:

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <div id="midnav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
            <li class="activesub"><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
</div>
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="main">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
html { min-height: 100%; height: 100%; margin-bottom: 1px; overflow-y: scroll;}
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    color: black;
    height: 100%;
}
a, a:active, a:hover, a:visited, a:link  {
  text-decoration:  none;
  font-weight:      none;
  background-color: none;
  color:       inherit;
} 
/********************/
/*** SUBNAVIGATIE ***/
/********************/
#navcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #464646;
}
#midnav {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 0.3em;
}
#midnav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: table;
}
#midnav li {
    display: table-cell;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 7px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 7px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0,1s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0,1s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0,1s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0,1s ease;
        transition: all 0,1s ease;
}
#midnav a {
    display: block;
        padding: 0.3em 1em 0.5em 1em;
}
.activesub, #midnav li:hover {
    color: #464646;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}

/********************/
/*** MAIN CONTENT ***/
/********************/
#maincontainer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}
#main {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #464646;
}

#maincontainer p {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Comment: I can't see any borders on IE9. Which version are you using?

Comment: Same for me i'm afraid, can't see any border or outline in IE9, it's possible it's not a border, but in-fact an `outline` - Try adding this rule `#navcontainer{ outline:0 }` Or to wherever it's occurring.

Comment: @cimmanon IE11, I added a screenshot as well

Comment: @LokeshSuthar IE11, I added a screenshot as well

Comment: @JackWilliams I added "outline" but it doesn't resolve the issue. I've  added a screenshot. Using IE11.

Comment: You have `display:table`, but I don't see a `border-spacing` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what causes the issue in IE, but the solution for the bottom 1px space is adding a 1px border to the LI element (**conditional IE CSS**)

```
#midnav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #464646;
}

#midnav .activesub, #midnav li:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a negative bottom margin to fix the miscalculation of IE..

```
margin-bottom:-1px;
```

Answer (score 0):

The line is coming from the background color of the `navcontainer` div.  The root of the problem is likely due to different font rendering between the browsers (especially given the odd-size scaling of 0.875em).  The `padding-top` property for the `midnav` div is 0.3em, a size based upon font rendering.  Changing this value to 6px, for example, aligns `midnav` and eliminates the problem:

```
#midnav {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
```

You can also see the difference when you disable the font-family property for the body.  IMO it's best to stick with pixels when aligning divs.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't look like it changes much here. However, I've found a solution by adding a border-bottom to the LI element.
Also, 0.875em is a default size - see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp

Comment: Sure, that works, too.  In any case, the issue isn't one of a gray border or outline on the `li` menu items, but rather a gap between the bottom of the bottom of the `li` items and the top of `maincontainer`, which exposed the gray background of `navcontainer` behind them.  How you choose to close that gap is up to you. :)

Thanks. I'm sure the default font size probably ran through my consciousness at some point, but I didn't recall it offhand.