# How to place border around multiple divs

Tags: html, css

I want to have a border around  multiple divs, so I was trying to set the border around the parent div. However, this leads to a slight gap between the children and the parent (One of the children will have a different background color). Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

https://jsfiddle.net/fpcg2x07/8/

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.child {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.child:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    child1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    child2
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want border around all the divs or the child divs

Comment: this happens because of  `padding: 0.5rem;`

Comment: @ITgoldman, I don't think so, if you remove the padding also, the space still persists, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945378/css-horizontal-menu-why-a-1px-border-space-in-ie-only) which is the same problem as this question

Comment: Is your browser zoom != 100% ?

Comment: I don't see any gaps in Chrome and Firefox, both in the snippet and in jsfiddle. What are you talking about?

Comment: for me in chrome without zoom there is a slight gap between the background color of the child and the border of the container

Answer (score 1):

The reason is still to be figured out. Maybe this happens because of the 0.5rem padding that for some reason doesn't coincide well with the fact that zoom of browser is different than 100%. That's why `px` unit is better(?) [Should I use px or rem value units in my CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799236/should-i-use-px-or-rem-value-units-in-my-css))

But here's a workaround (using borders for the child indeed, but only top and bottom).

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.child {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.child:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    child1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    child2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what my workaround was as well. It's kind of counterintuitive though. Does anyone know why the gap exists between the parent and the children?

Comment: I think you are seeing an edge effect when the browser has to decide how to map a part CSS pixel to screen pixels. There may be several screen pixels to one CSS pixel on modern screens. Sometimes a screen pixel gets ‘left behind’, sort of like a rounding error.